Excel TEXT function not filling cell when `* ` is present
I am trying to format numbers in Excel, and my desired outcome is similar to the Accounting format, where the $ is on the left and the value is on the right. I'm trying to include multiple numbers, so I need to use the TEXT function to convert each of them, and concatenate.
As a first step I tried to duplicate the behaviour of the Accounting format for positive numbers with the format string _‑$* #,##0.00_-, but it never has any space between the $ and the number.

Am I doing something wrong with the format string, or is there some Excel setting I'm missing that's preventing the TEXT function from filling the cell with spaces here?

If you want space after dollar sign $ then type space after $ inside format parameter. I have used 3 spaces to the following formula.
=TEXT(A1,"_‑$    * #,##0.00_-")



I could manually add spaces as you suggest, but that only works for particular cell widths. I'd like to be able to resize the cells, and still have the converted text behave the same way.

@lawruble13 Then go with cell formatting rather TEXT() function.

I can't do so, as I need to access two cells to determine what should be displayed. Are you saying that the "* " syntax doesn't work for the TEXT() function?
